# After changing domain name, should I create an XML sitemap with the old URLs?

Tags: google, google-search-console, 301-redirect, xml-sitemap

I've moved old domain to new domain. My site contains many pages (~30M indexed pages). I want to make sure all the old pages pass the link juice to the new domain relevant page (kept same URL structure).

I'm worried that if I submit a new sitemap for my new domain, it will get crawled without getting the link juice from the old domain. Should I keep a sitemap with the old domain URLs?

Comment: No. Sitemaps are for the sites they live on. You will want to create a blanket 301 redirect from the old domain to the new. Otherwise, you are starting over. I always recommend that everyone should seriously resist changing domain names. The new domain will have to stand on it's own eventually and cannot rely upon any older domain for long. As well, you lose SiteRank, TrustRank, etc. from the old domain. Some advantages do pass but not all. Changing domains always come at a price and sometimes that price surprises people.

Comment: @closetnoc I guess it surprises people because Google gives you the option to state in WMT that you are just changing the name. If a page has incoming links, wouldn't I be losing his power if I don't make sure google goes through that 301 I created?

Comment: I do not know what options exist in GWT, but you **do** want to create a 301 redirect from old site to new site on the site itself, for example, using .htaccess. You also want to remove the old sitemap from the old site and create a new sitemap for the new site. Sitemaps cannot reference anything off-domain including sub-domains so just do what you did before with your sitemaps just with a new domain name. It may be that the GWT changing domain option allows you to retain some SiteRank and TrustRank from the old domain which would be good.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm worried that if I submit a new sitemap for my newdomain, it will
>   get crawled without getting the link juice from the olddomain

Site position goes down, because Google may index your new site content and does not remove the old one **in a same time**, it take some time to understand that 301 redirection is done to this new URL, so we should transfer link juicy to this new URL, so in beginning all webmaster always suffer from lower position, but it will back soon once Google understand your both URL properly. Google also have [change of address tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en), which can [speed up the process very quickly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UU3xyhCXP9Q), because 301 redirection is done on page level, while this tool is dedicated at domain level.

> Should I keep a sitemap with the olddomain links?

Sitemap have nothing to do with ranking/linkjuicy. 1) you can redirect your old sitemap location to new sitemap location. 2) you can keep the old sitemap as it is, and Google will follow 301 redirection automatically 3) you can also add the newdomin link to your older sitemap. I have not done any case study to find which is clear winner, but with proper 301 redirection, Googlebot will surely remove the old one and index the new one automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should **NOT** put your old redirecting URLs into your sitemap.   Your sitemap should have only your preferred URLs in it.  All the URLs in your sitemap should be *clean*.   There shouldn't be any redirects, errors, or poor quality pages.  Your sitemap should consist of your best pages at their preferred URLs.

[Bing has said](https://moz.com/blog/bings-duane-forrester-on-webmaster-tools-metrics-and-sitemap-quality-thresholds):

> We have a quality threshold on our sitemaps. When you build a site map for us, we want it to be clean. When you put a URL into our site map, what I don't want to see in there is any URL that's a 404, 302, 301, anything at all. I want the end state URL only.

Google now puts warnings into Google Search Console if it detects redirects in your sitemap:

[image]

Reference: [Google Sitemaps Ask For Clean URLs](http://www.johnfdoherty.com/google-sitemaps-ask-for-clean-urls/)

Comment: Does not aware about these warnings. But It's fine if you add newdomain URL's into old sitemap, will it not return any warning?

Comment: Presumably if you have redirected the whole old domain, the old sitemap has been redirected too.   It should just be regenerated with the new URLs.

Answer (score 0):

My client has changed a domain old to new for re-branding purpose (2015) and we redirected (301) all the pages of old domain to new domain site. After few months we see that all of old domain pages backlinks are working for new domain. Off page SEO will work for your new domain.

So as far my little SEO experience I thank that you can redirect (301) to keep all previous backlink/link juice.

Comment: While this answer says that you can keep PageRank with redirects, it doesn't say whether an XML sitemap of the old URLs is a necessary part of the process.  Can you add that info?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermile. I didn't say it necessary part of the process. I had said to redirects all old URLs to new URLs.